# Monaca Localkit の UIを英語にするには

Tags: monaca

日本語以外のOSでも、Monaca Localkit の UIが、日本語のママのようです。英語にするには何か設定が必要でしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

Macならコマンドラインから

```
LOCALE=en open -a "Monaca Localkit"
```

で起動すれば英語になりますよ。（ローカルキットがアプリケーションフォルダにある場合）
もしくは

```
LOCALE=en open -a ~/path/Monaca\ Localkit.app
```

のようにパス指定でも良いです（ローカルキットが~/pathフォルダにある場合）

Windowsでも、環境変数でLOCALEをenにすれば英語になります。
（日本語にするときはja）